# Multiple file input, with stdin // Argparse4j, Java

Tags: java, file, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, stdin

I'm trying to use Argparse4j to build a command line utility. I need to create an option that accepts multiple input files, but also accepts stdin:

```
        subparser.addArgument("input")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                .nargs("*")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                .setDefault(Arrays.asList("-"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                .type(Arguments.fileType().acceptSystemIn().verifyCanRead());
```

If I don't use `Arrays.asList`, then sometimes I get just a `File` object, instead of a `List<File>`.

However, using `nargs("*")` also makes it so that I get "-" (as a String) in the list, instead of an actual `File` object.

Has anyone had any success with something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argparse4j does not do any conversion against the value passed by `setDefault()`.  So you need to pass `Arrays.asList(new File("-"))` to `setDefault()` to get desired effect.